# Error sending a multi-line string with \n and \t by SMS in android emulator

Tags: java, android, string, sms, string-formatting

I'm trying to send a multi-line string (I'm using \n and \t to format) from a TextView via sms to a second emulator.

**My problem** is that when I have these formatting operators in the string, the sms I receive in the emulator is comprised of greek letters and other symbols (I assume its the character encoding).

**Without** the formatting operators, and just the regular characters, the sms goes through no problem.

What is the issue here? Could it be that I need to use something other than "\n" or "\t" to format the string? Or is this only an issue with the emulator?

I used this method to send the SMS.

```
    // SMS Activity
    sendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSendSMS);
    sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            sendSMS("5556",mess);
        }

        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        }
    });
```

Populating the Text View, and setting the String equal to the Text View content.

```
   //Activity
    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inText = "";
        for(int counter=0;counter<=amt.length;counter++){
            if(amt[counter]==0){

            }else{
                String nameMess = name[counter];
                int amountMess = amt[counter];
                inText += "x"+ amountMess + "\t" + nameMess + "\n";
            }
        }
                Summary.setText(""+inText);
                mess = Summary.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```